# Importing lunr in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, lunrjs

The [Defintely Typed repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lunr/lunr-tests.ts) imports it like this:

```
import * as lunr from 'lunr';
```

However when using it like that in Stackblitz it errors with:

> lunr is not a function

Thoughts?  This is the Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lunr-test

Comment: Have you tried running this locally? This might be an error with StackBlitz

Comment: Yes I tried running it locally inside an Angular project.  It creates errors.  https://gist.github.com/fireflysemantics/5b9c8c385ab12dfe73d351e2d6351363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely Typed is using an [older version of lunr](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lunr/index.d.ts), so I tried a different import: `import lunr from "lunr"`, which throws an error saying `posting[field]` is `undefined` ([source code](https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js/blob/aa5a878f62a6bba1e8e5b95714899e17e8150b38/lunr.js#L2060-L2061)).

I then noticed that the `"text"` field being used in the `Builder` was not initialized in the `index`. Adding `this.field("text")` in the `index` resulted in the page loading without errors.

Comment: This seems to work, here's a link [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lunr-test-ou1zyz?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
import lunr from "lunr"
```

This way works because lunr.js is exporting a default or its overriding the export objects with a singular thing. Take a look at the first 4-5 paragraphs of this article: blog.atomist.com/typescript-imports

Comment: I edited your answer and up voted the question.  I would be cool to see an explanation of why that works instead of the way it worked in the past.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am more familiar with JS than I am with typescript. This way works because lunr.js is exporting a default or its overiding the export objects with a singular thing. Take a look at the first 4-5 paragraphs of this article: https://blog.atomist.com/typescript-imports/